# How to deploy with Composer, Symfony2, and something like Capistrano?

Tags: deployment, symfony, workflow, capistrano, composer-php

I'm trying to figure out a convenient workflow for using a deployer like Capistrano, with Symfony and Composer.

One problem I'm facing is that Capistrano requires the project to be in the repository (git) and that the server has access to it, but then how do I deal with this if I'm using Composer? Composer is the default dependency manager for Symfony 2.1+, and we are not supposed to include vendor/ in the repo (we specify this in .gitignore).

I haven't used Capistrano yet, I guess can add commands to be run on the remote production server, eg: 'composer update nothing' to refresh the lockfile. But how will I know that it worked? Can this be checked by adding more commands to the recipe?

If you know of any other deployers please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [capifony](http://capifony.org/). It's a collection of capistrano recipes for Symfony projects. Read more about it and learn how to use it from the official docs: http://capifony.org/

Capifony supports composer. You'll have to enable it maually (option [use_composer](https://github.com/everzet/capifony/blob/master/lib/symfony2.rb#L35)).

Comment: I must have missed that part. Thanks!